# how to remove one element from an array and append at the end using php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array which is sorted on the `active` value, like this:

```
patient = Array {

    [0] = Array {
           active = Y
           priority = o
                },

    [1] = Array {
           active = Y
           priority = P
                },

    [2] = Array {
           active = Y
           priority = S
                },

    [3] = Array {
           active = Y
           priority = T
                },

    [4] = Array {
           active = N
           priority = S
                }

          }
```

I want to take the element which has priority=`o` and append at the end without doing change in the sorting with active element. The output should be like this:

```
patient = Array {

    [1] = Array {
           active = Y
           priority = P
                },

    [2] = Array {
           active = Y
           priority = S
                },

    [3] = Array {
           active = Y
           priority = T
                },

    [0] = Array {
           active = Y
           priority = o
                },

    [4] = Array {
           active = N
           priority = S
                }

          }
```

The order of the key doesn't matter.

Comment: `what have you tried`?

Comment: in your desired example `priority = o` is not at the end?

Comment: This is trivial. In psuedocode: `push(arr, shift(arr))`

Comment: @Vector it has to be sorted by active first and then priority

Comment: @Vector: yes, it is mentioned that first it has to be sorted by active and then priority.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

```
// Comparison function
function cmp_priority($a, $b) {
    if ($a['priority'] == $b['priority']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a['priority'] == 'o' ? -1 : 1;
}

// Sort and print the resulting array using the comparison function
uasort($patient, 'cmp_priority');
print_r($patient);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to resort from array to priority queue, as it is optimized for that task.
Remember, how ever, that PQ is not availible on all installations.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.splpriorityqueue.php

```
$objPQ = new SplPriorityQueue();
$objPQ->insert('A',3); 
$objPQ->insert('B',6); 
$objPQ->insert('C',1); 
$objPQ->insert('D',2); 

//mode of extraction 
$objPQ->setExtractFlags(PQtest::EXTR_BOTH); 

//Go to TOP 
$objPQ->top(); 

while($objPQ->valid()){ 
    print_r($objPQ->current()); 
    echo "<BR>"; 
    $objPQ->next(); 
}
```